# Is it possible to jump to default case in match statement?

Tags: python, python-3.10

I've seen people using goto statements in C-like languages (C, C++, C#, etc.) to jump to different cases in a switch statement, but as this is not possible in Python, I wondered if there is another way to achieve that in a match statement which was introduced in Python 3.10 as a soft-keyword.

```py
number = input("Enter a two-digit number: ")
match len(number):
    case 2:
        try:
            number = int(number)
        except ValueError:
            # Jump to default case
        else:
            # Continue execution
    case _:
        print("You've entered an invalid number!")
```

The purpose is to print an error message in default case and jump to the default case when something is wrong in any other case, instead of rewriting the same error message, as can be seen in above example

Comment: No. Goto's are rather famously considered bad. Note, a match statement is *not a switch statement*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I know goto statements aren't a good thing to use. What's the difference between a match statement in Python and a switch statement in C?

Comment: A match statement uses *structural pattern  matching*, like you would see in functional programming languages like Haskell it is more akin to an expansion of the `a, b, c = some_iterable` syntax than a switch, which is essentially an optimized if..else..elif (an optimization which CPython does not use!)

Comment: You can think of a switch as a very narrow case of match, but structural pattern matching is much more expansive. Indeed, Python has explicitly rejected adding a simple switch for a long time, despite the proposal coming up more than once I believe.

Comment: I see. Kind of confusing stuff but thanks anyway for taking your time explaining to me! I'll use a function to avoid code repetition I guess... :)

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I think the match statement isn't needed.  You're looking for the input to consist of digits and to be a length of 2.  You can rule out invalid input at the top of your code and then continue your logic with the else statement.

```
if not (number.isdigit() and len(number) == 2)):
    print("You've entered an invalid number!")
else:
    number = int(number)
    # Continue execution
```

Comment: Actually the code I've sent in my question wasn't my case, it was just an example to visualize what I want. But if it was, yeah, this would be way better than using a match statement.